# Key windows in OS X development

Tags: swift, macos

### Issue

I'm developing a software for MacOS where the application window is displayed at the top when the shortcut key is pressed,

but after close the window, there is no key window on screen.I must click someone to make it as key window. I hope my app could work like this:

1. there is A application window is key window.
2. I press shortcut key and my app window show at the top
3. I close my app by shortcut key, and the A application window become key window again.

### Context

this is my code

```swift
let hostViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
self.mainWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: [.titled,.borderless,.closable,.miniaturizable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
self.mainWindow.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces,]
self.mainWindow.isMovable = false
self.mainWindow.title  = "test"
self.mainWindow.hidesOnDeactivate = true
self.mainWindow.order(.above, relativeTo: 0)
self.mainWindow.canHide = true
self.mainWindow.hidesOnDeactivate = false
self.mainWindow.contentView = hostViewController.view
self.mainWindow.orderFront(nil)
```

### What I've tried

1. Replace `NSWindow` with `NSPanel`
2. Set `isFloatingPanel = true`

but all failed. I search [apple document about nswindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000031-SW1) but look like nothing can help me.

Maybe there is no API to implement this requirement directly, so is there another way to implement it?

Comment: What if you use `makeKeyAndOrderFront` instead of `orderFront`? I think this should tell macOS that your window is key (and then the system will use 'resignKey' automatically to resolve which other window should be key after yours is closed).

Comment: @EricAya thank you for your comment ,I tried but failed.use `makeKeyAndOrderFront` instead of `orderFront` ,that my window become key ,but after close it, the previous app window can't become key window again until I click it.

Comment: Is the app a status bar app? How do you close the app?

Comment: well. This is my sloution:

1. before my app active, record `let targetApp = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication` 
2. after close my app window,execute `targetApp.activate()`

but there is a tiny bug: if `targetApp` have multiple windows, all windows will order front in some special cases